# IntelliJ IDEA Non-English Character Problem on Files

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea, unicode, encoding

I am woking on a spring project, the used language on this projects is Turkish but my systems layout and my keyboard is English. When I try to open project with Intelij IDEA, some characters are not seen, here is the example:

```
Kullan\u0131m Detaylar\u0131
```

This is what I see on the Intellij IDEA, but istead It should be like this:

```
Kullanım Detayları
```

This is just only one example some JSP files can be even worser,
One of my jsp file looks like this:

```
<span>Arýza Ýþlemleri</span>
```

But it should be look like this:

```
<span>Arıza İşlemleri</span>
```

This is also effects my WEB output, I tried to change some of the ide properties but nothing really changed.

Comment: Check the encoding of your files or the defaults of your project. Use UTF-8 if possible.

Comment: the encoding is UTF-8 for the spesific fiel but the characters are still unreadable

Comment: Then it's the font used in intellij that do't have those characters. choose another font.

Comment: `\u0131` is the unicode representation of `ı` it seems. IDEs tend to stick to ascii only to provide compatibility. You probably can change that somewhere in the settings but since I'm not an IntelliJ user I can't tell you where.

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer: no, missing glyphs would be represented by a rectangular character (usually empty, sometimes with the Unicode codepoint inside it). This is not a font problem.

Comment: It will help in future to give the output of ```System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));``` . Are you using WIndows?

Comment: Try adding `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` under `Help | Edit Custom VM Options` and restart the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

It is a decision, but best do all in UTF-8. Sources, JSP sources, properties and so on.
Ensure that the compilers, javac, jspc also use UTF-8. This will allow special Unicode characters like bullets, emoji and many more.

You could still deliver a Turkish page in a Turkish encoding like ISO-8859-3. But UTF-8 would do too.

`\u0131` (dotless i, `ı`) is an encoding to ASCII. You can use this to test that the encodings are correct.

In IntelliJ set all the encoding in the preferences and the project. If you have an infrastructure like maven or gradle, set it there. For the compiler.

Possibly check with a programmer's editor like NotePad++ that the encoding is correct.

And last but not least check the database, tables/columns stored as UTF-8.

User form entry should also accept UTF-8, so the data does not go encoded as numeric entities to the server (=more efficient).

Answer (score -1):

Do not use Turkish characters, instead use their unicode representatives.For example for "ı" use "\u+0131"